# converting EBCDIC to ASCII in Perl

Tags: perl

How can I convert EBCDIC to ASCII In Perl. I tried with dd command in linux and it worked fine. Can anyone help me out the same in Perl?

Comment: This is essentially a programming question, and would be best placed in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a Perl module that can help with that, however I did not use it, so i cannot help you further. By looking at its documentation, it looks simple though.

> [Convert::EBCDIC](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Convert-EBCDIC/lib/Convert/EBCDIC.pm)
>
> Convert::EBCDIC, ascii2ebcdic, ebcdic2ascii - Perl module for string
> conversion between EBCDIC and ASCII

Example usage from module's description:

```
use Convert::EBCDIC;
$ascii_string = ebcdic2ascii($ebcdic_string);
$ebcdic_string = ascci2ebcdic($ascii_string);
 
$translator = new Convert::EBCDIC;
$translator = new Convert::EBCDIC($table);
$ascii_string = $translator->toascii($ebcdic_string);
$ebcdic_string = $translator->toebcdic($ascii_string);
 
$Convert::EBCDIC::ccsid819
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Encode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) module (which has been a standard part of the Perl distribution since Per l5.8.0 in 2002).

Either use `decode()` to convert your EBCDIC into Perl characters and `encode()` to convert your characters into ASCII, or use `from_to()` to carry out the conversion in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

perl from 5.8 has built-in EBCDIC handling with `Encode`. See the man page [perlebcdic](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlebcdic.html) for details and examples.  There are several EBCDIC variants. `dd conv=ascii` and the reverse `dd conv=ebcdic` seems to use code page `cp1047`, so the following should work:

```
echo 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz[]<>()01234567689' |
dd conv=ebcdic | 
perl -e '
use Encode "from_to";
$a = <>;
from_to($a,"cp1047","latin1");
print $a."\n";
' - |
cat -vet
```